# Removing comment option

Tags: comments, templates

I am working on a theme that I found here: http://top-wordpress.net/ The theme is Terapy. I turned off comment option in the admin panel, but the blog posts show that "commenting is not allowed". I want to completely turn off comments, so that the blog looks like a site (nothing about comments should appear in posts and pages). How can I turn off commenting in the above templates.

In the index.php I removed this line:

```
<span class="metaComments"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>#comments"><?php comments_number('0 Comments','1 Comment','% Comments'); ?></a></span>
```

Now the posts in the front page don't show how many comments are there. Now only thing that should be done is completely removing commenting option from the template. How can it be achieved?

Edit: I misspelled the name of the theme. [Here is the link to the demo](http://demo.top-wordpress.net/MagPress3/?preview_theme=Teraphy)

Comment: I cannot find any theme by that name. Is it public/free? Link to it?

Answer (score 1):

Remove [`comments_template()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comments_template) function from `single.php` template.

By the way quick scan with [Theme-Check](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/theme-check/) shows that theme contains hardcoded links and runs obfuscated code, not even mentioning massive amount of missing or poorly coded features. I'd not use it without major scrub of internals.

Comment: There's far too many of these dodgy theme sites around. Best suggestion would be to find a better source, such as the WordPress theme repository(where you can be assured it won't contain nasty code). Additionally these themes are usually outdated, running old code, and several versions behind the theme they're typically ripping off and i'd not even go as far as suggesting to clean the theme, that's side stepping the bigger problem of thinking it's a good idea to be downloading themes from such sites.

Comment: Not to mention the fact that the site is in violation of the WordPress copyright restriction on domain names...